# MassIndexer does not index anything

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, indexing, hibernate-search

I am having a problem with the MassIndexer that brings me to my head, first of all I feel if my English is a little bad, I am using the translator a lot

I am using Java 8, Hibernate search 6 and Elasticsearch 7 and I am running into a very weird problem, when I run massIndexer it does not index anything, everything else does it well, the automatic indexing when creating, modifying or deleting database entities, the searches are done without problems but when executing massIndexer the result is always "HSEARCH000028: Mass indexing complete. Indexed 0 entities" and it ends without more, there is not a single only error message or exception, nothing, the first step of cleaning the elasticsearch indexes does it well, but when indexing always ends with "HSEARCH000028: Mass indexing complete. Indexed 0 entities"

I have tried to get more logs, debug, test the entityManager in case it failed on that side, I have changed the versions of the libraries, I have searched the internet and I do not see the same problem and the cases that look alike are from very old versions and more things I don't even remember, but there's no way it works.

So I desperately need help because I'm stuck at that point and I don't know what else to do.

This is my configuration from the AplicationConfig:

```
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.enabled","true");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.automatic_indexing.strategy","session");
        
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.hosts", "127.0.0.1:9200");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.protocol", "http");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.username", "");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.password", "");
        
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.backend.type", "elasticsearch");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.automatic_indexing.synchronization.strategy", "sync");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.schema_management.strategy", "drop-and-create");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.automatic_indexing.enable_dirty_check","true");
```

And the code to run massIndexer is the same as the hibernate search 6 documentation for easy testing:

```
        SearchSession searchSession = Search.session( entityManager ); 
        searchSession.massIndexer().startAndWait();
```

Any additional information you need just tell me and thank you very much in advance

-----Edited-----

Thank you very much for the reply yrodiere

I have tried:

- entityManager.createQuery ("select count (o) from java.lang.Object o") .getResultList ()
- Search.mapping (entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory ()). AllIndexedEntities ();

In both cases they have given me the expected data so that on that side everything is correct

I put below the logs of the massIndexer, I have not been able to put those of the beginning of the application because it exceeds the character limit:

```
[14/09/21 11:52:12.089][DEBUG][MassIndexerImpl.<init>] Targets for mass indexing: [MassIndexingIndexedTypeGroup[commonSuperType=es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.DatPatientDateEntity, includedSubTypes=[es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.DatPatientDateEntity]], MassIndexingIndexedTypeGroup[commonSuperType=es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.DatPatientStringEntity, includedSubTypes=[es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.DatPatientStringEntity]], MassIndexingIndexedTypeGroup[commonSuperType=es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.DatPatientTokenEntity, includedSubTypes=[es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.DatPatientTokenEntity]], MassIndexingIndexedTypeGroup[commonSuperType=es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.PersonaEntity, includedSubTypes=[es.indra.hn.ispob.modelo.entity.PersonaEntity]]] 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.107][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientdateentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 10ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.121][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientstringentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 10ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.125][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientdateentity-write/_delete_by_query', query parameters {conflicts=proceed} and 1 objects in payload in 11ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <{"query":{"match_all":{}}}>. Response body: <{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.136][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatienttokenentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 12ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.143][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientstringentity-write/_delete_by_query', query parameters {conflicts=proceed} and 1 objects in payload in 13ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <{"query":{"match_all":{}}}>. Response body: <{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.145][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/personaentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 11ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.155][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatienttokenentity-write/_delete_by_query', query parameters {conflicts=proceed} and 1 objects in payload in 10ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <{"query":{"match_all":{}}}>. Response body: <{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.162][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/personaentity-write/_delete_by_query', query parameters {conflicts=proceed} and 1 objects in payload in 9ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <{"query":{"match_all":{}}}>. Response body: <{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.178][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientdateentity-write/_forcemerge', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 7ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.190][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientstringentity-write/_forcemerge', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 10ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.196][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatienttokenentity-write/_forcemerge', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 6ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.205][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/personaentity-write/_forcemerge', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 8ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.206][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.208][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.211][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.212][TRACE][BatchTransactionalContext.wrapInTransaction] TransactionFactory does not require a TransactionManager: don't wrap in a JTA transaction 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.212][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.211][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.214][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.214][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.221][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.224][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.291][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.292][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.294][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.301][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.307][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.297][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.316][DEBUG][BatchIndexingWorkspace.runWithFailureHandler] Indexing for DatPatientDateEntity is done 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.317][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.330][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.331][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.331][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.331][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.331][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.331][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.331][TRACE][BatchTransactionalContext.wrapInTransaction] TransactionFactory does not require a TransactionManager: don't wrap in a JTA transaction 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.335][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.342][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.405][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.407][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.408][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.410][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.410][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.410][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.413][DEBUG][BatchIndexingWorkspace.runWithFailureHandler] Indexing for DatPatientStringEntity is done 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.414][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.421][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.422][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.426][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.428][TRACE][BatchTransactionalContext.wrapInTransaction] TransactionFactory does not require a TransactionManager: don't wrap in a JTA transaction 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.429][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.430][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.435][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.436][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.438][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.498][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.498][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.502][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.504][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.505][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.505][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.506][DEBUG][BatchIndexingWorkspace.runWithFailureHandler] Indexing for DatPatientTokenEntity is done 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.507][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.510][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.511][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.514][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.<init>] created 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.515][TRACE][BatchTransactionalContext.wrapInTransaction] TransactionFactory does not require a TransactionManager: don't wrap in a JTA transaction 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.515][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.519][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.520][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.523][TRACE][IdentifierProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.523][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] started 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.581][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.581][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.584][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.581][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.585][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.581][TRACE][IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run] finished 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.588][DEBUG][BatchIndexingWorkspace.runWithFailureHandler] Indexing for PersonaEntity is done 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.615][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientdateentity-write/_flush', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 11ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.626][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientstringentity-write/_flush', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 11ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.641][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatienttokenentity-write/_flush', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 14ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.656][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/personaentity-write/_flush', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 10ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.676][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientdateentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 11ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.688][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatientstringentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 12ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.711][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/datpatienttokenentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 17ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.729][TRACE][ElasticsearchClientImpl.log] HSEARCH400093: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' with path '/personaentity-write/_refresh', query parameters {} and 0 objects in payload in 8ms. Response had status 200 'OK'. Request body: <>. Response body: <{"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}> 
[14/09/21 11:52:12.729][INFO ][LoggingMassIndexingMonitor.indexingCompleted] HSEARCH000028: Mass indexing complete. Indexed 0 entities.
```

According to the logs, the indexed entities are well recognized, which are: DatPatientDateEntity, DatPatientStringEntity, DatPatientTokenEntity and PersonaEntity

The versions I am using are:
Hibernate Search 6.0.6
Hibernate ORM 5.4.4.Final

Answer (score 0):

First, the obvious: check that there is something in your database when you execute the mass indexer. I know, it's dumb, but mistakes happen. If you use that exact entity manager to run `entityManager.createQuery( "select count(o) from java.lang.Object o" ).getResultList()`, do you get any non-zero result?

If you get only zeros:

- Maybe your database was not initialized properly. For example your data initialization script might be missing a "COMMIT" near the end, or your initialization script might not have been executed at all.
- Maybe `entityManager` is not pointing to the right database (the one you initialized). It could be pointing to a distinct, embedded H2 database, for example. Check your JDBC connection settings.
- Maybe you're using multi-tenancy and this particular tenant has no data. Be aware that the mass indexer will only reindex the tenant assigned to your current `EntityManager`.

Second, check that your `entityManager` is what you expect. If use that exact entity manager to call `Search.mapping(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()).allIndexedEntities()`, do you you see all the entity types you expect? If not, I'd wager you created the `EntityManagerFactory` yourself, and it's not the same used when you create/update/delete entities. Check the code that retrieves the `EntityManager` used for mass indexing, or the code that retrieves the corresponding `EntityManagerFactory`.

Lastly, if none of the above reveals any problem, try enabling trace logging for `org.hibernate.search`, and edit your question to include all the logs (startup + mass indexing). And please also mention the exact versions of Hibernate Search (6.0.x) and Hibernate ORM (5.4.x) you are using.